# Which Certificate Type and Provisioning Profile Type should I use for Test Flight

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, testflight

We are setting up a Continuous Deployment server with a MacOS-node for iOS-builds. The build itself is working correctly. However, we have difficulties in signing the app. As we want to do testing within a dynamically growing test-pool, we're currently using TestFlight (integrated into iTunesConnect). This is currently done via XCode-GUI and is working perfectly fine. As we want to move the manual process to CD-server, this needs to be done via command line.

Currently what is there so far

- building & archiving

`xcodebuild archive \
    -project $xcodeproj.xcodeproj \
    -scheme $xcodeproj \
    -archivePath $xcodeproj.xcarchive \
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$common_name"`

- exporting to ipa-file

`xcodebuild -exportArchive \
    -archivePath $xcodeproj.xcarchive \
    -exportPath $xcodeproj \
    -exportFormat ipa \
    -exportProvisioningProfile "$provisioning_profile"`

- validation

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Support/altool \
    --validate-app \
    -f $build_dir_ios/project/$ipa_file \
    -u $testflight_user \
    -p $testflight_pass`

However, the validation tells me that my provisioning profile is incorrect. The response of the validation is as follows.

`2015-12-04 18:53:30.308 altool[63218:8786237] *** Error: Unable to validate archive '/Users/deploy/jenkins/workspace/***/build/ios/project/***.ipa': (
    "Error Domain=ITunesConnectionOperationErrorDomain Code=1176 \"Unable to process application at this time due to the following error: Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle *** [Payload/***.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal..\" UserInfo=0x************ {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Unable to process application at this time due to the following error: Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle *** [Payload/***.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal.., NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to process application at this time due to the following error: Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle *** [Payload/***.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal.., NSLocalizedFailureReason=iTunes Store operation failed.}"`

As this failure is probably certificate / provisioning profile based, that's how we created the two of them.

1. login to https://developer.apple.com as admin
2. go to **Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles**
3. add a new certificate of the type **iOS App Development**, which will later on be displayed as **iOS Development**
4. add a new provisioning profile connected to a certain app-version of the type **iOS App Development**, which will later on be displayed as **iOS Development**

**Questions:**

1. Which certificate / certificate type should be used here?
2. Which provisioning profile should be used here?
3. How to later on push the app only for TestFlight via command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ A Distribution one

2/ An App Store one

3/ You cannot, except if you use tools like https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane (pilot)

Good luck

Nicolas